# Обработка данных различных типов и форм записи

Tags: python, база-данных, структуры-данных

Следующий вопрос в первую очередь касается подходов и методов в обработке данных разного типа, и во вторую - реализации этих действий в каком-то инструменте или языке, в моем случае я использую `python` и реляционную БД

Имеется массив данных такого типа

```html
obj\prop| property1   | property2 | property3   | property4
__________________________________________________________
id=1    | 3.4*10^3 m  |   'CID23' |    3.4  W   |   12.3 %
id=2    | 5.4*10^16 m |   'AA323' |      223 W  |   23 %
id=3    |   235  m    |   'dID23' |    null     |  0.0003 %
id=4    |   null      |   null    |     222  W  |  10^(-3) %
id=5    |   null      |   'CID33' |    null     |   null
id=5    |   0.6 m     |   null    |    null     |   12.3 %
id=5    |   673   m   |   null    |     234  W  | 99.23423 %
...
id=N    |   5378 m    | 'test234' |     3.4  W  |   42.3 %

null - отсутствие данных
```

Как видно значение свойств может быть представленно:

1. строкой (как в столбце property2): 'CID23', 'Silver', 'RandomString'
2. целым числом: 235, 0, -10000
3. числом с дробной частью: 2.2, 0.234, -123.5
4. числом в экспоненциальной записи: 3.4*10^3, 0.666*10^33, -3.213*10^(-84)
5. отсутствовать: null

Пункты 2,3,4 можно объединить в один - все числа можно представить в экспоненциальной системе, да простят меня математики, если я несу ересь.

Некоторые свойства имеют единицы измерения (W, m, % и т.д).

Тип данных не смешивается внутри столбца - данные могут быть либо строковые+null, либо числа+null, одинаковое свойство не может описывать строкой и числом.

И собтсвенно вопрос. **Какой моделью можно описать все эти свойства?**

Если бы все данные были бы преставленны числами, я бы учел их перевод в экспоненциальную запись (мантисса, основание, степень) и создал модель

```
 mantissa | base | significand | unit
```

в которой бы данные `3.4*10^34 m` можно было бы представить как

```
 mantissa | base | significand | unit
 3.4      | 10   |     34      |   m
```

c строковыми данными все еще проще, например для 'CID23'

```
  value   | unit
  CID23   |  m
```

Однако, в моем случае я не нашел ничего лучше, как объединить эти модели
в одну, в которой "ненужные" поля зануляю. Для двух примеров таблица в БД выглядит так

```
 mantissa | base |  value  | significand | unit 
    3.4   | 10   |  null   |     34      |   m
   null   | null |  CID23  |    null     |   null
```

Есть ли какой-то более изящный способ обрабатывать данные подобного типа?